# Fast fixed-size (256 bit) integer modulo/division

Tags: algorithms, c, math

What is the fastest way to divide two 256-bit integers? They are represented as an array of 26-bit words, each stored in 32-bit integers. I have access to a 64-bit type if that's useful.

It seems like fast division methods in the literature all assume we are dividing a 2n-word number by an n-word number. Is there some simple transformation or folklore that lets me generalize these methods to arbitrary numbers?

Comment: find a existing bigInt divide and optimize for your case?

Comment: Java's digs down to "Uses Algorithm D in Knuth section 4.3.1. Many optimizations to that algorithm have been adapted from the Colin Plumb C library" (from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/MutableBigInteger.java#792))

Comment: ... I assume you looked at the code in BigInteger that I linked above. Is there a reason that didn't work for you?

Comment: I'd like to point out that you are (likely) a math or cs phd student (according to your SE profile). Programmers.SE tends to be the much more pragmatic industry programmers rather than the designers of new algorithms or deep understanding of existing ones. If its in the standard library - there are other problems and deadlines to be had rather than worrying about reimplemeting the wheel (until the profiler says that its not rolling fast enough). You might have better luck asking on CS.SE or TCS.SE.

Comment: Is the problem in efficient unpacking the 26-bit words?

Comment: @MichaelT I am a math Ph.D. student, but this problem is unrelated to that. This is development of a high-performance cryptography library (libsecp256k1), where we do care about deep understanding of our algorithms, both for perf reasons and to be assured that there are not weird edge cases which may have security implications.

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra my point is that the audience of people asking questions here, and the experts providing the answers consists largely of people with a bachelor of science in CS, a certificate program, or are self taught. We are the line of business coders and the architects of applications. We use the standard libraries and accept that they work well enough for our needs and deadlines. With few exceptions, we don't have or need the deep understanding of what is going in with some algorithm that Knuth came up with for numerical methodology - those aren't the problems we are trying to solve.

Comment: My concerns with the Java algorithm are its lack of clear commenting (though I think the analysis I want to see is actually in Knuth) and the age of the algorithm. Having said that, I expect in the end I will wind up using that algorithm since it is the best I have found. However compare libgmp which has dozens of algorithms spread across thousands of lines of code (but even more sparsely commented!), which shows that there is better stuff out there. I was hoping somebody somewhere had written some of this out. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelT Also,thanks for your comments on the audience here. I will keep this in mind for future postings (and might move this to CS.SE).

Comment: Googling for "fast integer division algorithm" gave me a lot of links to modern, well documented resources beyond Knuth, did you try some of them?

Comment: @DocBrown, yes, I have been Googling since before I posted this question. As I mentioned all the well-documented sources have this assumption that the dividend is twice the size of the divisor, which suggests that their algorithms are supposed to be a component of something more generic (which does normalization or something to get stuff to this form, or selects from multiple algorithms, or something).

Comment: I've found a lot of the folklore I've been missing in http://wbhart.blogspot.de/2010/10/bsdnt-divrem-discussion.html and http://wbhart.blogspot.de/2010/10/bsdnt-v014-divremclassical.html

Comment: I realize this is old but I just now came across it: I adapted Knuth's Algorithm D for the multiprecision divide-and-remainder code found in the BSD `qdivrem.c` code: http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/common/lib/libc/quad/qdivrem.c (incidentally the reference to "root boy jim" is to Pete Cottrell's brother Jim Cottrell, who no doubt used that moniker in reference to [Root Boy Slim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_Boy_Slim).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is test if divider and dividend are equal, in which case the result is 1, if the divider is bigger than than the dividend, in which case the result is 0 and if the divider is zero, in which case the result is undefined.

Then if both values are small enough to fit a 64 bit integer, you convert both to 64 bit and make a normal 64 bit integer division, like:

```
int256_from_64(int265_to_64(intA) / int265_to_64(intB))
```

And if you have fast methods that "divide 2n-word number by an n-word number", you can use them in case the divider is 128 bit or less, as then you are dividing a 256 by a 128 bit number (just expand one to 256 and the other one to 128).

If both are above 128 bit, you can either pretend the first one to be 512 and again use a "divide 2n-word number by an n-word number"-method (this time it will be 512 and 256) or you implement division by hand which is not that horribly slow if you don't want to crunch billions of numbers a second.

```
if D = 0 then error(DivisionByZeroException) end
Q := 0                  -- Initialize quotient and remainder to zero
R := 0                     
for i := n − 1 .. 0 do  -- Where n is number of bits in N
  R := R << 1           -- Left-shift R by 1 bit
  R(0) := N(i)          -- Set the least-significant bit of R equal to bit i of the numerator
  if R ≥ D then
    R := R − D
    Q(i) := 1
  end
end
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Integer_division_(unsigned)_with_remainder